How to interpret training and validation loss graph in Keras, is it a good fit?
I've trained a Keras model and obtained a graph with training and validation loss curves. The graph shows the following pattern:  enter image description here
Can someone help me interpret this graph? Is this a good fit? How can I determine if my model is overfitting or underfitting based on this graph?
I still have yet to tweak the parameters but this is by far the best result that I have obtained. the accuracy score of the model is 61% and I am sure I can achieve better scores by tweaking the code but I am trying to learn about the graph whether it is an underfit, good fit, or an overfit and based on that I want to move forward with the model.

If the model was overfitting you'd see validation loss increasing at the end (see here). You might want to double check the reason for the validation loss being lower than the training loss (see here).
